# JUnit - Catch an exception in the @After section

Tags: junit, exception, try-catch

I have this scenario in which some tests can throw different exceptions.

```java
@Test
public void addDevice(){
    device.addDevice(); // this may throw exception 1
    device.verifyStatus("Ready");
    device.open();  // this may throw exception 2
    device.verifyStatus("Open"); 
}

@Test
public void otherTest(){
    device.act(); // this may throw exception 3
    device.verifyStatus("Ready");
}

@After
public void tearDown(){
    // handle the exception here
}
```

I want to handle those exceptions in the `@After` section without wrapping the test with `try`, `catch`.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible.

You could wrap the test anyway with a try-catch-block. Then you could store the exception to a member variable instead of handling it.
In the `@After` method you can check whether the exception is null or not.

Comment: Already thought about it but I have hundreds of tests and I'm trying to avoid that solution.

Comment: What about doing that logic in an ``@Before`` method in an abstract class? Would it be possible that your test classes inherit that class?

Comment: Not sure I'm following you... How can @Before help me?

Comment: You can extract the code which throws the exception in a method which is inherited by all test classes. So you have to do it only once.

Comment: That's not possible, it's not the same code in each test

Comment: Then you need your own test runner. See the ``@RunWith`` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Due to your comment that you have hundreds of tests with this code I assume that this is set up logic which should actually be in an `@Before` method.

Thus, you could specify an external resource rule with a before and after method: https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Rules#externalresource-rules

In the `before()` method you perform the set up, catch and store the exceptions and in the `after()` method you handle them.

But does it make sense to handle the exception later? Can you run your test cases successfully if the set up fails?